# Can't init array with uint8 type

Tags: arrays, types, nim-lang

I try to init array with the following expression:

```
const a: array[3, uint8] = [1, 2, 3]
echo repr(a)
```

Compiler output:

```sh
Error: type mismatch: got <array[0..2, int]> but expected 'array[0..2, uint8]'
```

Is there a conventional way to do it?

Comment: I don't know anything about nim, but I looked in [the docs](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#lexical-analysis-numerical-constants) and it looks like you can suffix your numbers with `'u8`. Did you try that?

Comment: Thank you for the note. The following works: `const a: array[3, uint8] = [uint8(1), 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are initializing an uint8[] with an int[] expression. In order to initialize it properly, you need to use compatible literals.

For example:

```
const a: array[3, uint8] = [1'u8, 2, 3]
```

By marking the initial element of an array expression as an uint8 using the 'u8 suffix, you make the whole array expression an uint8[].